# Изменить владельца процесса в unix

Tags: unix

Можно ли изменить владельца процесса и как? UID менять? Есть такие команд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делают системные вызовы семейства setuid.
(См. `man 2 setuid` и SEE ALSO в нем)