# Как запустить процесс от другого пользователь Linux C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, c

Мне хотелось сделать на подобее /bin/login и т.п. или попытается запускать процесс от другого пользователя

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/380551/178576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать [SETUID бит](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Comment: Это работает при условие если программа от root, а если как например команда sudo которая запускается у обычного пользователя, а процесс запускается от root

Или login, он тоже может запускаться от обычного пользователя

Comment: @Redis,  `ll /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 149080 Jan 31 20:18 /usr/bin/sudo*`

Comment: @avp Получается чтоб сменить пользователя от другого пользователя нужно чтоб сама программа принадлежала root,у??

Comment: Именно так. Только у root есть полномочия стать произвольным пользоватем